# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for for each () in Wordpress

Tags: arguments, warnings, invalid-argument

Please Help!! Getting an following Error.

It says something is wrong in 'taxonomy-coupon-store.php, but couldn't find anything wrong?

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/searche1/public_html/wp-content/themes/Deals/taxonomy-coupon_store.php**

Here is my taxonomy-coupon-store-php file:

ID, 'coupon_store' );
    foreach ( $store_obj as $element ) {
        $store_id = $element->term_id;
        $store_name = $element->name;
        $store_description = $element->description;
        $store_count = $element->count;
        $store_url = get_term_link( $element, 'coupon_store' );
    }
    $store_url = get_metadata('coupon_store', $store_id, 'junkie_store_url', true);
    $store_aff_url = get_metadata('coupon_store', $store_id, 'junkie_store_aff_url', true);
    $store_image_preview = junkie_get_store_image_url($store_id, 'term_id', 100);
    ?>

```
<header class="page-heading clearfix">  

    <div class="entry-thumb-wrapper">
        <a href="<?php echo $store_aff_url?$store_aff_url:$store_url; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $store_image_preview; ?>" class="store-thumbnail" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>             
    </div><!-- .entry-thumb-wrapper -->
        <div class="entry-excerpt">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo $store_name; ?></h1>
            <p class="store-url"><a href="<?php echo $store_aff_url?$store_aff_url:$store_url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $store_url; ?></a></p>            
            <p class="store-desc"><?php echo $store_description; ?></p>
        </div><!-- .entry-excerpt -->
</header><!-- .page-heading -->

<div class="content-heading clearfix"> 
    <h3><?php _e('Active Coupons','junkie'); ?></h3>
</div><!-- .content-heading -->     

<?php

    if ( have_posts() ) :

    while(have_posts()) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content');
    endwhile;
     else :
        get_template_part( 'coupon','none');

    endif;

    wp_reset_query();

?>
    <?php 
        junkie_pagination();
    ?>

<div class="content-heading clearfix"> 
    <h3><?php _e('Unreliable Coupons','junkie'); ?></h3>
</div><!-- .content-heading -->

<?php
    $args=array(
        'post_type'=>'coupon',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_status' => 'expire',
        'orderby' => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'expire_date',
                'value' => current_time('mysql'),
                'compare' => '<',
                'type' => 'DATE'
            )
        ),              
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'coupon_store',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term->slug
            )               
        )               
    );

    $recent = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $recent->have_posts() ) :

    while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content');

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();

else :
    get_template_part( 'coupon', 'none' );
endif;
?>

</div><!-- #content -->
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="content-loop" role="main">

    <?php
    $taxonomy='coupon_store';
    $term = get_queried_object();
    //get my store.
    $store_obj = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'coupon_store' );
    foreach ( $store_obj as $element ) {
        $store_id = $element->term_id;
        $store_name = $element->name;
        $store_description = $element->description;
        $store_count = $element->count;
        $store_url = get_term_link( $element, 'coupon_store' );
    }
    $store_url = get_metadata('coupon_store', $store_id, 'junkie_store_url', true);
    $store_aff_url = get_metadata('coupon_store', $store_id, 'junkie_store_aff_url', true);
    $store_image_preview = junkie_get_store_image_url($store_id, 'term_id', 100);
    ?>

    <header class="page-heading clearfix">  

        <div class="entry-thumb-wrapper">
            <a href="<?php echo $store_aff_url?$store_aff_url:$store_url; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $store_image_preview; ?>" class="store-thumbnail" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>             
        </div><!-- .entry-thumb-wrapper -->
            <div class="entry-excerpt">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo $store_name; ?></h1>
                <p class="store-url"><a href="<?php echo $store_aff_url?$store_aff_url:$store_url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $store_url; ?></a></p>            
                <p class="store-desc"><?php echo $store_description; ?></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-excerpt -->
    </header><!-- .page-heading -->

    <div class="content-heading clearfix"> 
        <h3><?php _e('Active Coupons','junkie'); ?></h3>
    </div><!-- .content-heading -->     

    <?php

        if ( have_posts() ) :

        while(have_posts()) : the_post();
            get_template_part( 'content');
        endwhile;
         else :
            get_template_part( 'coupon','none');

        endif;

        wp_reset_query();

    ?>
        <?php 
            junkie_pagination();
        ?>

    <div class="content-heading clearfix"> 
        <h3><?php _e('Unreliable Coupons','junkie'); ?></h3>
    </div><!-- .content-heading -->

    <?php
        $args=array(
            'post_type'=>'coupon',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_status' => 'expire',
            'orderby' => 'DESC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'expire_date',
                    'value' => current_time('mysql'),
                    'compare' => '<',
                    'type' => 'DATE'
                )
            ),              
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'coupon_store',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $term->slug
                )               
            )               
        );

        $recent = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $recent->have_posts() ) :

        while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'content');

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();

    else :
        get_template_part( 'coupon', 'none' );
    endif;
    ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->


<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```